# Create table using select statement in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, jupyter-notebook

I have connected my SQL Server to Python using `sqlalchemy`. Now I'm trying to use select statements to create 3 separate tables and ultimately join them. But none of my queries can ran through. Here's my code:

```
query2 = """
select AML_CUST_ID as AML_CUST_ID0,DATA_DT as DAY0,sum(CAST(AMT as float))as AMT0 into AML_Testing_DAY0 from dbo.trial2 
group by AML_CUST_ID,DATA_DT
"""
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(query2); 
connection.execute("SELECT * FROM AML_Testing_DAY0")
```

Even though this code can run with no error, there's no table created in SQL Server. I have read on stackoverflow that this only creates a temp table, not a permanent table. Is there a way to create a permanent table? Thanks in advance for any inputs

Comment: Did you have a `commit()` somewhere in your code?

Comment: It looks like you're relying on autocommit, but SQLA does not recognize your statement as a data changing operation.

Answer (score 0):

It will create a permanent table. Are you sure you're in the right database in the context of your session? Try adding three part naming, with the database before your schema/tables. If that's not the issue, try starting a trace with SQL Server Profiler to see what is happening.